# Visual Studio open with live server option

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

With using Visual Studio Code, i can right click on html file and there is a option:

[image: open with live server]

using this [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer)
if i open the page with c\this option, and changes detected in editor (after save) will automatically refresh the browser.

Is it possible to achieve such a behavior in Visual Studio 2017?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the feature is called 'Browser Link'. You can find the setting options under Tools -> Options -> Web

[image]

**Update -**

These option are only available with 'Web Extension package 2017'. Download from [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebExtensionPack2017).

Once installed you can enable disable the settings from 'Debug' options. 
[image]

Comment: I dont have these options under web, did you installed them?

Comment: What version of VS2017 do you have? You might need to install the 'Web Extension Pack 2017' from installer.

Comment: Here's the link that might help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/using-browserlink?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: You don't need to install the meta packages if you install the Web Extension from your VS installer. Otherwise it's the same thing.

Comment: i lost you, what do i need to install then?

Comment: Here's the link of Extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebExtensionPack2017

Comment: You need to enable it on "debug target"  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/using-browserlink?view=aspnetcore-2.1#how-to-use-browser-link

Comment: did you see it working on `.net framework` project, and not `.net core` ?

Comment: I do.. and I use it all the time.

Comment: ok thaks. now its working:) dont know why it didn't work before

Comment: please add to the answer the link for [Web Essentials](Web Essentials 2017)