# How to install Live Server on Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, npm-live-server

I have just started my first job today and my new employer uses Visual Studio and not Visual Studio Code which was what I've been learning and using for the last few months. I normally use Live Server or NPM start on VS Code. However my new boss instructed me to use 'Debug' > 'Start without debugging' which shows all my edited work but this is extremely slow as I'm use to Live Server updating my edits in real-time. I've tried looking around to see how to install Live Server on Visual Studio but all I find are resources for VS CODE!!

Comment: According to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52819944/visual-studio-open-with-live-server-option Web Essentials might help you.

Comment: That is what I initially tried but cant find Browser Link